# Range Slider with direct number input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is it possible to utilise a range slider in a form field and also allow a user to input the value through typing a number, i.e. having input type="range" and input type="number" on the same form field with the one utilised overriding the other?

Ok, so in response to the below here is my code:

```
<label for="monday">Monday Sales Target - $<span id="monday"></span></label>
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="monday" name="monday" value="0" step="50" oninput="showValue1(this.value)" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function showValue1(newValue) { 
    document.getElementById("monday").innerHTML=newValue;
}
```

At the moment the range slider changes and outputs the number selected at the end of the label however some users are complaining that the slider is too fiddly and would like to enter the number directly through a number input. Is this possible?

Comment: It depends on the situation, can you post your actual code?

Comment: Any ideas chsdk?

Comment: I posted an answer showing a solution that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `range` value change according to the `input` value using `onkeyup` event with the `input`, here's what you will need:

**HTML:**

**JS:**

```
function changeRangeValue(val){
    document.getElementById("range").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
    showValue1(val);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function showValue1(newValue) { 
    document.getElementById("monday").innerHTML= newValue;
}

function changeRangeValue(val){
    document.getElementById("range").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
    showValue1(val);
}

function changeInputValue(val){
    document.getElementById("number").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
    showValue1(val);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" min="0" max="5000" onkeyup="changeRangeValue(this.value)"/> 
<br />

<label for="monday">Monday Sales Target - $<span id="monday"></span></label>

<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="range" name="monday" value="0" step="50" oninput="changeInputValue(this.value)" />
```

**Note:**

You can't set the same `id` for multiple elements in HTML.

Comment: This is amazing, is there any way to change the number displayed in the type="number" if the range selector is used, I'm not sure if there is an equivalent to onkeyup for the range selector?

Comment: @user1419810 Yes you can use a function that changes the `ibput` value, in the `oninput` event of the range element, I edited my answer.